# Deep linking react native app on Android

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

I'm trying to get make a url open the app and to have some data with this url passed into the app, but it doesn't work.

My activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">                         <-- added this
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="fcm.ACTION.HELLO" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <data 
        android:scheme="conv"
        android:host="convid"/> <-- so urls of the form 'conv://convid/ will open the app
     </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

And I added to the entry class of the app:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    Linking.addEventListener('url', (e) => {
      console.log("url", e);
    });

    Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
      if (url) {
        console.log('Initial url is: ' + url);
      }
    })
  }
```

But when I open the browser and go to `conv://convid` nothing is being logged and the app doesn't open.

Of course I opened my app before the browser.

Comment: Did you check out the React Native docs on [linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html)?

Comment: @alexdriedger yep, I edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The app will not open if the link is entered into the browser's address bar. It has to be a web page `<a/>` tag like:

  `<a href="http://example.com"></a>`

link inside some page. (https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents)

As you probably do not have a web page to put  tag inside, for your tests you can use adb command. Open the console and write the following line:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "YOURHOST://YOURSCEME/" com.YOURAPPNAME
```

for example in your case it should be something like (change YOURAPPNAME with the name of your app):

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "convid://conv/" com.YOURAPPNAME
```

- if you are using windows and, and if it says adb command is undefined you need to run the command from platform-toolsfolder inside your SDK folder such as:

  `Android/Sdk/platform-tools/`

Comment: I placed the link in jsfiddle.net and opened it from the emulator, it worked. Why they don't mention this in the react native docs...