# URL scheme is working correctly for ios but not for android in react native

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking, url-scheme

> I have tried almost all the solutions and variations to make this work. May be I am missing something trivial but I am not able to figure it out.

> Following is the code for my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="com.linkup">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      tools:targetApi="28"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="linkupcaribbean" android:host="paymentsuccess" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />   
    </application>

</manifest>
```

> I have also tried opening 'intent://paymentsuccess/#Intent;scheme=linkupcaribbean;package=com.linkup;end' from browser and  app as mentioned in https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents but this also didn't seem to work.

> Tried this [Deep linking react native app on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45927123/deep-linking-react-native-app-on-android) and other similar ones too.

> I am returning below code from App.js

```
return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {/* {currLang = useSelector((state) => state.language.language)}
      {strings.setLanguage(currLang)} */}
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <AppNavigator uriPrefix={'linkupcaribbean://'} />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  )
```

> And in my Navigator

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Tabs: ShopBottomNavigator,
        SearchLocation: SearchLocationScreen,
        SearchByWords: SearchByWordsScreen,
        Discover: DiscoverScreen,
        DiscoverSubCategory: DiscoverSubCategoryScreen,
        ShowAllBusiness: ShowAllBusinessScreen,
        ShowAllBusinessWithFilters: ShowAllBusinessWithFiltersScreen,
        BusinessDetail: BusinessDetailStack,
        ShowAllEvents: ShowAllEventsScreen,
        ShowAllFavouriteEvents: ShowAllFavouriteEventsScreen,
        Filters: FiltersScreen,
        AddBusiness: AddBusinessScreen,
        ManagePayments: ManagePaymentsScreen,
        ShowAllProducts: ShowAllProductsScreen,
        ShowAllFavouriteProducts: ShowAllFavouriteProductsScreen,
        EventDetail: EventDetailStack,
        Notifications: NotificationsScreen,
        ShowAllDeals: ShowAllDealsScreen,
        ProductDetail: ProductDetailStack,
        MyCart: MyCartScreen,
        OrderDetail: OrderDetailScreen,
        EditProfile: MyProfileScreen,
        MyWallet: MyWalletScreen,
        ManageCard: ManageCardScreen,
        ShippingAddress: ShippingAddressScreen,
        PrivacyPolicy: PrivacyPolicyScreen,
        TermsAndConditions: TermsAndConditionsScreen,
        AboutApp: AboutAppScreen,
        GetHelp: GetHelpScreen,
        ChangePassword: ChangePasswordScreen,
        AddEditAddress: AddEditAddressScreen,
        AddReview: AddReviewScreen,
        Checkout: CheckoutScreen,
        AddNewCard: AddNewCardScreen,
        AllReviews: AllReviewsScreen,
        ShowReview: ShowReviewScreen,
        DealDetail: DealDetailScreen,
        PromotionDetail: PromotionDetailScreen,
        BuyerManagePayment: BuyerManagePaymentScreen,
        FilterEventScreen: FilterEventScreen,
        FilterProductScreen: FilterProductScreen,
        PaymentSuccess: {
            screen: PaymentSuccessScreen,
            path: 'paymentsuccess'
        }
    },
    {
        defaultNavigationOptions: {
            header: null,
        }
    }
);
```

> I am using react-navigation 4

Answer (score 0):

change this according to your requirement

```
export const RootNavigator = () => {
  const deepLinking = {
    prefixes: ['https://www.example.com'],
    config: {
      AuthNavigator: {
        initialRouteName: 'Registration',
        screens: {
          Login: {
            path: 'Login/:token',
            params: {
              token: '',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={deepLinking}>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={Splash} />
        <Stack.Screen name="AuthNavigator" component={AuthNavigator} />
        <Stack.Screen name="MainNavigator" component={MainNavigator} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

this is my authNavigator in case you need it

```
export const AuthNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: true,
        header: ({navigation}) => (
          <Header onBackPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
        ),
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="OnBoarding"
        component={OnBoarding}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Registration"
        component={Registration}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="Registration1" component={Registration1} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
      <Stack.Screen name="LocationAccess" component={LocationAccess} />
      <Stack.Screen name="AddressDetails" component={AddressDetails} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

and add this intent filter below existing intent filter in android manifest

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
             <data android:scheme="https"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/Login" />
          </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Could you change this to react-navigation 4?